# Do $n \times n$ diagonalizable matrices with equal eigen values commute with all $n \times n$ matrices$?$

Tags: linear-algebra

Do $n \times n$ diagonalizable matrices with equal eigen values commute with all $n \times n$ matrices$?$

If we write such diagonalizable matrix in Jordan form then it will commute with all $n \times n$ matrices.

Do these matrices still commute, without writing these in Jordan form $?$

Comment: You can show it must be $\lambda I$. But of course someone was faster to the party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is diagonalizable and all its eigenvalues are equal to $\lambda$, then there exist two matrices $T$ and $D$ such that:

$$ A = TDT^{-1},$$ 
where $D = \lambda I$ (recall that $T$ is the change of base matrix composed by the eigenvectors of $A$).  Therefore:

$$A = T(\lambda I) T^{-1} = \lambda T T^{-1} = \lambda I.$$

Since $A$ is multiple of the identity, then it commutes with any other matrix. Indeed, given a generic matrix $B$ we have that:

$$AB = (\lambda I)B = \lambda IB = \lambda B = \lambda BI = B (\lambda I) = BA.$$

Comment: Think you meant since A is a multiple of the identity instead of diagonal.

Comment: @Manuel right, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Say $A$ is diagonizable and all its eigenvalues equal $\lambda$.

Then, the corresponding diagonal matrix is $\lambda I_n$.
But then, if you take $P$ to be the change of basis matrix, $A = PDP^{-1} = P(\lambda I_n)P^{-1} = \lambda P P^{-1} = \lambda I_n$ :).

So $A$ is simply $\lambda$ times the identity. Hence, it does commute with all matrices.